# LDAP server to LDAP client password sync issue

Tags: ldap

When we are changing users password on the LDAP server and then user are able to make new password by the use of random password. The problem is user is able to use his previous password also on the some servers. Although if we changed the users password on the LDAP server then previous password should not work for login.

Why previous password still working?

How to resolve the issue? I hope password synchronization happening delay.

Comment: You don't describe how authentication is working on those servers. Are you doing LDAP bind or something else?

Comment: Come to think about it. You didn't specify which LDAP server you were running (MS AD, Samba, sssd OpenLDAP etc).

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Active Directory, then take a look at this page: [New setting modifies NTLM network authentication behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/new-setting-modifies-ntlm-network-authentication), which says:

> Domain users can use their old password to access the network for one hour after the password is changed.

This only applies when NTLM is used.